# How to resolve 'showsSelectionIndicator' in iOS 13?

Tags: ios, deprecated, ios13

My application has a picker and I want to display the indicator. It was really simple, just use this code:

```
self.picker.showsSelectionIndicator = true
```

Unfortunately `showsSelectionIndicator` is now deprecated and I found nothing how I could resolve it. Is there no more ways to display the indicator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you cannot show/hide the indicator in iOS 13. That is a feature left over from IOS 6.

Comment: Thanks @matt! Just found the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipickerview/1614373-showsselectionindicator): _The selection indicator is always shown [...]_